# JDBC driver class not found error in struts-hibernate integration project

Tags: java, hibernate, struts

I am working on struts-hibernate integration project. When I enter data in input JSP, the output JSP shows text result as data stored in database. But actually no data is getting stored &  showing the following `error`:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: JDBC Driver class not found: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

1 more thing I wanna ask is a new  window has popped up titled as`"JLoEndpoint.class"` which had message as source not found with
- The JAR file `C:\program files\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\lib\tomcat-coyote.jar` has no source attachment. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be sure to have the jar containing the driver in the classpath.
If you do not have the jar, you can download it from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java

Comment: i have already added all d jars required in the library of my project . 
dont know whats d problem. m stucked at one this point. i m trying hard .   
btw thanks all of u.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download jar containing  `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` [you can download jar from here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommysqljdbc515jar.htm)   and set your `classpath`

Comment: i have already added all d jars required in the library of my project . 
dont know whats d problem. m stucked at one this point. i m trying hard .   
btw thanks all of u.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have not included the com.mysql.jdbc.Driver into the class path of your project. 
1.First download the mysqldriver
2.if you are using the eclipse than go to Project->BuildPath->Configure Buil path -> Libraries Tab - > Add external jar and than select the mysql driver jar which you have downloaded
3. Rebuild or clean the project 
4.Deploy the project again.

Comment: i have already added all d jars required in the library of my project . 
dont know whats d problem. m stucked at one this point. i m trying hard .   
btw thanks all of u.

Comment: If you are using tomcat server than goto apache tomcat6.0->Lib folder and manually add the jar over there and restart your server and than check. If you are using other server than search for the lib folder and than add your jar over there. Let us know the result....